# React hook not setting the state

Tags: reactjs

Hey all trying to use a useState react hook to set a state but it does not work, I gone through the [official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)

Seems like i have followed it correctly but still cannot get the hook to set the state:

```
const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
const { films } = props;

const matchMovieSearch = (films) => {
    return films.forEach(item => {
        return item.find(({ title }) => title === search);
    });
}

const handleSearch = (e) => {
    setSearch(e.target.value);
    matchMovieSearch(films);
}




<Form.Control 
                type="text" 
                placeholder="Search Film" 
                onChange={(e) => {handleSearch(e)}}
            />
```

Search var in useState is allways empty even when i debug and can see that e.target.value has to correct data inputed from the html field

Comment: it seems there are parts of your code that you did not share with us. Hooks can only be used inside a component.

Comment: it is a functional component, and i import the useState like so 

import React, { useState } from "react";

function troll () {
//code here
}

Comment: Add it to the question please. A few more questions for you. What makes you say state is not being set? How are you checking? Is the hook declared within the component body?

Answer (score 1):

`setSearch` is an async call, you won't be able to get the `search` immediately after setting the state.

[useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) is here for rescue.

```
useEffect(() => {
    // your action
}, [search]);
```

Comment: This is most likely the problem. To elaborate - When they try to use `title === search`, `search` will not be updated yet.

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant.

Comment: Yep, not contradicting you. Just adding some clarity as to where the specific problem is, since the problem is within `matchMovieSearch` and not a problem with state updates like the OP suggested.

Comment: @BrianThompson yup, Agreed.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are using the hooks inside a component, hooks can only be used in a Functional React Component.

If that is not the case, there must be something wrong with the `Form.Control` component, possibly like that component did not implement the `onChanged` parameter properly.

This is the one I tested with the html input element, and it is working fine. I used the `useEffect` hook to track the changes on the `search` variable, and the you can see that the variable is being properly updated.

https://codesandbox.io/s/bitter-browser-c4nrg

```js
export default function App() {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`search was changed to ${search}`);
  }, [search]);

  const handleSearch = e => {
    setSearch(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <input
      type="text"
      onChange={e => {
        handleSearch(e);
      }}
    />
  );
}
```